# how to access path response

Tags: python, lxml

I an trying to scrape a share price from yahoo finance. I don't understand Xpaths too well so I don't know how to access the value that is returned

```
from lxml import html
import requests

r = requests.get('https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/BVXP.L?p=BVXP.L')
root = html.fromstring(r.content)
price = root.xpath('//*[@id="quote-header-info"]/div[3]/div/div/span[1]')
```

I've checked the xpath using XpathHelper in chrome, and it returns the value I'm looking for (3,325.00 - or whatever is the quote at that point.)

However in Python, I don't know how to access that info.

```
print(price)
# Returns [<Element span at 0x108832278>]
```

What's the correct way of doing it?

Comment: `print(price[0].text)`

Answer (score 0):

try `print(price[0].text)`, you see price is a list with one item, and just by indexing we access the info you wanted.

a little FYI, if you ever get stuck always try to look at what methods it possess by `print(dir(price[0]))` this is just an illustration from your example, but just by looking at the methods and attr of the object it gives us a glimpse, where to ahead.